# How to draw route between multiple LatLong Android map?

Tags: android, google-maps

Am working on an Android project where I want to draw route between 2 point on Google Map. I have successfully drawn route between source and destination point. But I have 1 problem in that, i.e. Some times I want to draw a path between more than 2 point, That time the code that I have written is drawing route between first and the last position and leaving the mid point position. What I exactly want is my route should go through the mid point to the destination point. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can separately draw routes between three point. So, first draw the route from starting point to mid point then from mid point to end point. Then if you want add the required markers.

Comment: With the approach you suggested, one would actually require redundant code snippet doing the same thing and will also be costly operation in terms of device performance. And if there are many points then with your approach it's nightmare.

Comment: Using PolylineOptions documented in Google API's, the same task will be quite easier and straight forward to do. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PolylineOptions from GoogleMaps API [Dcoumented Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions) and keep adding all the points which should be a part of your route. You can do something like this

```
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
```

Hope this solves your problem.